# Apache (WAMP) refusing HTTPS connections

Tags: apache, ssl, wamp

I`m running WAMP server v3.1.3 under Win Server 16, hosting several web sites. Everything was fine until I decided to add an SSL certificate to one of my sites (Apache virtual host). Now the web server is refusing HTTPS connections to that site from outside, but I am able to properly access the site, locally through HTTPS. All other sites are working fine/unimpacted. Obviously I messed up the config somewhere, but not sure where, probably its a silly mistake.

In httpd.conf, I have enabled the ssl_module, socache_shmcb module and I have included the httpd-ssl.conf. Also I've put the ceritificate and key inside the Apache conf folder. Httpd is saying Sintax is OK and I was not able to detect any errors in the logs. Most other settings have their default values. The web server should be listening on port 443, but is refusing connections from the outside. Locally I can access the site normally and its indicating the HTTPS properly. I access it locally and remotely using the same url (https://...; 3) Locally the site is working as it should, with HTTPS; remotely I`m getting "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" HTTP error. Apache version is 2.4.33; 
Any help will be much appreciated!

Here are some hints:

**httpd-vhosts.conf** looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile 
"C:/WAMP64/bin/apache/apache2.4.33/conf/key/certificate.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/WAMP64/bin/apache/apache2.4.33/conf/key/key.key"
SSLCACertificateFile "C:/WAMP64/bin/apache/apache2.4.33/conf/key/ca.crt"

ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/domain"
<Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/domain/">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/domain"
<Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/domain/">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName site2.domain.com
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/site2"
<Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/site2/">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**httpd-ssl.conf** looks like this:

```
Listen 443

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES

SSLHonorCipherOrder on 

SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLSessionCache        
"shmcb:C:/WAMP64/bin/apache/apache2.4.33/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

DocumentRoot "c:/WAMP64/www"
ServerName domain.com:443
ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
ErrorLog "C:/WAMP64/bin/apache/apache2.4.33/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/WAMP64/bin/apache/apache2.4.33/logs/access.log"

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile "C:/WAMP64/bin/apache/apache2.4.33/conf/key/certificate.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/WAMP64/bin/apache/apache2.4.33/conf/key/key.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/WAMP64/bin/apache/apache2.4.33/conf/key/ca.crt"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "C:/WAMP64/www">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
     nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
     downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog "C:/WAMP64/bin/apache/apache2.4.33/logs/ssl_request.log" \
      "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Try adding `Allow from all` inside your vhost `Directory` statements. Are you able to access non-https from outside?

Comment: 1) How do you access it locally vs from remote (which URL) ? 2) Which Apache version? Before 2.3.11 you need a `NameVirtualHost` directive. 3) What exactly happens when it does not work? No reply at all, a TLS error message, an HTTP error code?

Comment: @pmahomme - thanks for the suggestion, I tried Allow from all, but no change

Comment: @PatrickMevzek hi, 1) I access it locally and remotely using the same url (https://...; 2) Apache version is 2.4.33; 3) Locally the site is working as it should, with HTTPS; remotely I`m getting "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" HTTP error

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Of course the reason was a silly mistake - port 443 was not opened in my router :)